# Multi-sorted data structure

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to implement A* and I ran into a problem. I have a set where I need to find the minimum value of a given function, but I also need to be able to check if a given cell is in that set. In order to do this efficiently, I need the set to be sorted by position and value. It doesn't seem too difficult to write such a data structure. I just need one sorted by position and one by value, and have each refer to the other. There are two problems with this. First, in order to do it well, the structures need to be able to refer to parts of each other. There's no point in searching through a tree in log time if I can just point to the particular element. In order to do this, I'd pretty much need to rewrite trees from scratch. Second, it doesn't seem like the sort of thing I should be writing. Data structures are supposed to be part of the libraries. What's the name of the sort of data structure I need, and where can I find a C# library for it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the two data structures to interact at all.  Just have two data structures side by side.  Make sure that when you add/remove an item you add/remove it from both.  You can then fetch the minimum value of either collection based on which property you're interested in.

The only real reason to create a new data structure would be to ensure that adding/removing items was kept in sync between the two collections.  There would be no need to manipulate the actual trees explicitly.

Such a custom type would look something like this (other operations omitted; they all just delegate to `first` and/or `second`).

```
public class SetPair<T>
{
    private SortedSet<T> first;
    private SortedSet<T> second;

    public SetPair(IComparer<T> firstComparer, IComparer<T> secondComparer)
    {
        first = new SortedSet<T>(firstComparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default);
        second = new SortedSet<T>(secondComparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default);
    }

    public T FirstMin { get { return first.Min; } }
    public T SecondMin { get { return second.Min; } }

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        return first.Add(item) &&
            second.Add(item);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return first.Remove(item) &&
            second.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not optimized though. It takes longer to search for a value in a set then it does to just to have the memory address to begin with.

Comment: @DanielLC If you would prefer to just store the min value in a variable and re-compute it whenever adding/removing an item, you could do that as well.  Which is faster is going to depend on how often the collection changes relative to how often you fetch the min value.  You could also cache the min values and just invalidate the cache when the sets change.

Comment: @DanielLC In that case trying to cache the values wouldn't save you anything, and you're better off just using something like what I provided as is.